# Is there a Guard Clause Utility/Helper class for Java?

Tags: java

Is there a Guard Clause utility class for Java? I wrote a simple one, however, I would like to see and learn from what other people have done.

Comment: You mean like [`Objects.requireNonNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-)?

Comment: And Guava? https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained

Comment: Something like that, but the language is more like; `Guard.AgainstNull(user)`

Comment: @Nayuki Thanks. That's what i was looking for.

Comment: googles guava is the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Guava's [`Preconditions`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) class and its [overview](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained).

Also there are some utilities in the Java standard library, such as [`Objects.requireNonNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-).